# ASP.NET MVC Routing Challenge

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one site on asp.mvc.
Have some folders and aspx pages in my root directory, like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
           "Reports", 
           "{folder}/{action}.aspx", 
           new {controller = "Reports", action = "Publisher" }
        );
```

And then have some Test controller and view in Views folder:

```
routes.MapRoute(
              "Test",
              "Test/{controller}/{action}", 
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
          );
```

This cause some conflict in Home controller, it starts searching Reports controller and etc.
How can i solve it?

Comment: MVC Routes are fall through from top to bottom. Switch the order and it should work.

Comment: No, it starts to fail in other:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pages, you need to use **MapPageRoute** instead, like this:

```
routes.MapPageRoute("",
        "Category/{action}/{categoryName}",
        "~/categoriespage.aspx");
```

Check the detailed explanation on the link below:

[ASP.NET Routing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx)